Build failed in Storybook webpack config caused by svg
this error occurs when launching storybook, all svg that i use in the application cause an error
in ./src/shared/assets/icons/about-20-20.svg ...etc
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/@svgr/webpack/dist/index.js):
if i remove all references to svg from the application, then all components in the storybook work correctly
webpack.config.ts storybook webpack config
import webpack, { DefinePlugin, RuleSetRule } from 'webpack';
import path from 'path';
import { buildCssLoader } from '../build/loaders/buildCssLoader';
import { BuildPaths } from '../build/types/config';


export default ({ config }: {config: webpack.Configuration}) => {
    const paths: BuildPaths = {
        build: '',
        html: '',
        entry: '',
        src: path.resolve(__dirname, '..', '..', 'src'),
    };
    config.resolve.modules.push(paths.src);
    config.resolve.extensions.push('.ts', '.tsx');

    // eslint-disable-next-line no-param-reassign
    config.module.rules = config.module.rules.map((rule: RuleSetRule) => {
        if (/svg/.test(rule.test as string)) {
            return { ...rule, exclude: /\.svg$/i };
        }

        return rule;
    });

    config.module.rules.push({
        test: /\.svg$/,
        use: ['@svgr/webpack'],
    });
    config.module.rules.push(buildCssLoader(true));

    config.plugins.push(new DefinePlugin({
        __IS_DEV__: true,
    }));

    return config;
};


main.ts storybook config
import type { StorybookConfig } from "@storybook/react-webpack5";

const config: StorybookConfig = {
    stories: [
        '../../src/**/*.stories.@(js|jsx|ts|tsx)'
    ],
    addons: [
        "@storybook/addon-webpack5-compiler-swc",
        "@storybook/addon-onboarding",
        "@storybook/addon-links",
        "@storybook/addon-essentials",
        "@chromatic-com/storybook",
        "@storybook/addon-interactions",
    ],
    framework: {
        name: "@storybook/react-webpack5",
        options: {
            builder: {
                useSWC: true
            }
        },
    },
    docs: {
        autodocs: "tag",
    },
    swc: () => ({
        jsc: {
            transform: {
                react: {
                    runtime: 'automatic',
                },
            },
        },
    }),
};
export default config;


